# Unity - First Person Controller - unwanted behaviour with "non kinematic"

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, kinematics

I have a problem with my First Person Controller.

I need a Rigidbody with "Is Kinematic == false" due to a wanted collision-trigger with a enemy.

But if I set my Rigidbody to non Kinematic - the FPS Controller freaks out and switches Positions while walking. Sometimes the view goes up or down.

If I set "Is Kinematic == true" everything works fine.

I dont have any parts of my Rigidbody in my code.

Here is a screenshot of my FPS-Controller-Inspector:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my hierarchy (Please ignore the "RigidBodyFPSController" - its not in use.):

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my scene, where you can see the problem. My FPS-Controller-View is to high. It should be in the same height of the zombies. Without "Is Kinematic == false" - everything works.

[image]

let my know if you need further information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Comment: Generally mixing `CharacterController` and `RigidBody` can lead to weird results - often caused by the two different systems fighting for control. That said, take a look at [this comment on Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/comments/548952/view.html) for a similar problem.